# Multiple responses in Stata

Tags: stata

Let's say you have a survey dataset, with 12 variables that stem from the same question, and each variable reports a response option for that question (multiple-response options possible for this question). Each variable (i.e. response option) is numeric with yes/no options. I am trying to combine all of these variables into one, so that I can do cross-tabs with other variables such as village name, and draw out the frequencies of each individual response and graphs nicely without extensive formatting. Does anyone have a solution to this: either to combine the variables or to do a multivariable cross-tab that doesn't require a lot of time spent on formatting?

Example data:

```
  A B C D E F
```

1. 1 0 1 0 1 0
2. 0 0 1 0 1 1
3. 1 1 1 0 0 0

Comment: I've removed the tag `variables`, as I think it won't help anyone. I'd say this problem is most discussed in Stata circles under the heading "multiple responses", so I would recommend putting that in your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many tricks and techniques here.

Tricks include using `egen`'s `concat()` function as well as the `group()` function mentioned by @Dimitriy V. Masterov.

Techniques include special tabulation or listing commands, including `tabm` and `groups` on SSC and `mrtab` at the *Stata Journal*; on the last, see [this article](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0082).

See also [this article in the Stata Journal](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0008) for a general discussion of handling multiple responses.

Comment: Thank you! the first article on mrtab is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Does `egen pattern = group(A-F), label` do what you desire? If not, perhaps you can clarify what the desired transformation would look like for the 3 respondents you have shown.